# How to automate a paperclip upload to amazon s3 in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have some images that I want to move from `myBucket/...` to `myBucket/someFolder/...`.  I have paperclip and aws-sdk setup to put new images in that location when uploaded on a form, but I can't figure out how to move the images to the location defined in production.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :url  => ":s3_eu_url",
    :s3_protocol => "https",
    :path => ":class/images/000/000/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

How do you call paperclip on an image in a remote location in a controller method?  I want something in my illustrationsController like the following:

```
def convert
    @illustration = Illustration.find(params[:id])
    Paperclip.someMagicMethod(@illustration.image_url)
end
```

Thanks.